# Android path.move() and path.lineTo() will draw twice

Tags: java, android, path

`path.move(90,90)`;
`path.lineTo(100,110)`;
`path.move(100,110)`;
`path.lineTo(110,120)`;
the point (110) will draw twice but I want it to be drawn once . So what should I do?

I want to draw a translucence line, but there are some points to be repeated, color burn?

Comment: what happens when you skip the 2nd `path.move(100,110)`?

Comment: it must be like path.move(0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a connected line you can write

```
path.move(90,90); path.lineTo(100,110); path.lineTo(110,120);
```

Comment: if path not move (100,110) ,is not a line. i want the three point is a line

Comment: @Kam what is the class of your `path` object?

Comment: i konw what's wrong.it is mySurface Problem. think you very much

Answer (score 0):

path.moveTo(x coordinate, y coordinate) method must call once. It sets the starting point of your line.